# @media запросы, container

Tags: html, css, media-queries, containers

Мои медиа запросы выглядят примерно так

```
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1140px;
  }
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 720px;
  }
```

и так далее, но почему то появляется небольшая прокрутка по горизонтали, как будто контейнер с правой стороны пропадает(знаю похоже на бред сумасшедшего), хотя через панель разработчика всё ок, что это может быть

сайт на котором можно посмотреть мои начинания - http://sizovleonid.ru/

P.s Будьте терпимей я только обучаюсь)

Comment: У вас у `container` ширина `max-width: 720px`, а у элементов задана ширина `720px`, получается, что при любом разрешении экрана у Вас блоки будут 720px, сделайте их тоже резиновыми

Comment: аааа, спасибо))))

Comment: не за что, желаю успехов!